# Do you lose quality converting from a lossy audio format to a lossless format?

Tags: conversion, encoding, file-format

I know that you lose quality going to a lossy format.

```
Examples:
flac > mp3
ogg > mp3
```

But do you lose quality going from it?

```
Example:
mp3 > flac
```

Bonus question: What about images?

```
Example:
jpg > png
```

Comment: To be pedantic, technically you can actually still lose quality when converting to a lossless format. If you convert a JPEG to an 8 bit PNG file for instance, you would be losing colour information. Same can apply to music files based on sample rate, bit depth etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Nope.

When you convert from FLAC to MP3 (or whatever formats), the converter has to essentially re-record the file. It would be like taking a video of a video, or taking a photo of a photo; of course you're not going to maintain the quality of the original.

However, when you convert from MP3 to FLAC, you're simply decompressing the MP3 and taking the raw sound of whatever is there. No quality loss. Of course, as James Polley pointed out in the comments, you can't gain quality out of nothing in this way.

This applies to audio, video, images, etc.

Comment: Cool.  Glad to here it.  Can you please supply a reference of some sort?

Comment: But you also won't gain any quality: the conversion can't put back what isn't there.

If you convert from a lossy format to a lossless format and then back to a lossy format, you'll usually have lost quality compared to your original lossy-format file.

Comment: @James: Of course not. Who said you'd gain any quality? ;)

Comment: Lossy formats, by definition, do not lose data - they contain the full data of the file. They're a 1:1 representation of the sound that comes out of your speakers, or the image displayed on your screen.

Comment: To make it clearer: in order to play the audio, or display the image, the original file has to be converted to a lossless format for output. Once it's in that lossless format, saving it in a lossless format does not lose any data.

Comment: @James: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm having a hard time understanding how that conflicts with what I said.

Comment: technically you a) decompress the MP3 (to raw WAV/PCM data); then b) recompress that raw data to the FLAC.  it's lossless compared to the MP3 -- if you decompress both, you should get identical WAV data (the true test of lossy vs lossless formats -- once decoded, is it the same data?)

Comment: @musicfreak no conflict at all :)

Comment: @James: Ah okay, I thought you were trying to prove me wrong. Sorry for the misunderstanding. :) I don't know the low-level details, I just know the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @James: "Lossy formats, by definition, do not lose data" Did you mean **Lossless** formats?

Answer (score 0):

You should never convert from MP3 to another audio format such as AAC, AIFF, ALAC, or FLAC, as all you will be doing is making the file bigger.

MP3s are lossy compressed files whereas with lossless files, the file sizes are a lot bigger but don't degrade in quality compared to MP3. With lossless the sound sounds better, but what you're actually doing by decompressing an MPEG from lossy to lossless is degrading the sound quality. All you will get is the same quality recording, just in a larger file.

If I were you I'd stick to MP3. Don't convert from MP3 to another format or it will just sound the same as before maybe worse. If you want to change the format then you will need to re-rip or re-download from the original source using the new conversion settings you desire. Don't convert from MPEG. It's a waste of time and effort as all you will be doing is making the file larger, and it won't improve your sound quality, it will only make it worse than the lossy version.